# Javascript styling on mouseover not working

Tags: javascript, css, mouseover

In my project, the following line of code doesn't seem to be working and I am not sure why. If anyone could explain the mistake i would be grateful

```
for (i = 0; i < playertiles.length; i++) { 
playertiles[i].onmouseover = function() {
    characterscroll();
    if (p1==true){
        if (this.classList.contains('contestant1')) {
            document.getElementById('contestant1upper').style.MozBoxShadow = "0px 0px 7px 7px rgba(199,12,12,1)";
            document.getElementById('contestant1upper').style.webkitBoxShadow = "0px 0px 7px 7px rgba(199,12,12,1)";
            document.getElementById('contestant1upper').style.boxShadow = "0px 0px 7px 7px rgba(199,12,12,1)";
            uppertext[0].style.color = "D51D20";
            uppertext[0].style.textShadow = "2px 2px 2px #600808;";
            uppertext[0].style.innerText = "P1";
            uppertext[0].style.visibility = "visible";
        }
```

All variables have been defined. The `contestant1upper` styles function, its the `uppertext` that is giving me grief.

Attached is a link to my project for you to have a closer look.
[Link to project](http://eg-graphics.com/zwooper/codedepisodes/MemoryWall.html)

Thank you in advance everyone!

Comment: `style.innerText`? remove `style` here

Comment: Amazing, thank you :) @wostex